# Copy row to a new sheet when checkbox selected

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy all the data from one row (from columns A:O) to a new sheet once the checkbox has been selected. However, the code that I have is also copying all the previously checked rows as well. I don't want to deselect any previously checked boxes.

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim LRow As Long, ChkBx As CheckBox, WS2 As Worksheet
    Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    LRow = WS2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each ChkBx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
        If ChkBx.Value = 1 Then
            LRow = LRow + 1
            WS2.Cells(LRow, "A").Resize(, 14) = Range("A" & _
            ChkBx.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(, 14).Value
        End If
    Next
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code so we can read it better.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the modified code below with ActiveCell.Row (this is assuming that the last check box row is selected/active).

```
Sub CopyRows()
    Dim LRow As Long, r As Long, ChkBx As CheckBox, WS2 As Worksheet
    Set WS2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    WS2.Cells(r, "A").Resize(, 14) = Range("A" & ChkBx.TopLeftCell.Row).Resize(, 14).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the modified code. Yes, your assumption was correct. I've coped the code, assigned the macro, but when I select any of the checkboxes nothing happens. I tried running the code in VBA, but it's producing no results.  Thank you for reformatting!
@Cconard96, thanks for the comment. Tried to reformat, but I posted it incorrectly and couldn't save the edit.

Comment: @puffyharley I modified the answer.